# CSS: z-index:-1 and background: transparent doesn't work

Tags: html, css

See my picture:

[image]

My note of CSS:

[image]

I'm stuck at here. It supposed to be a vertical line there (continued from bottom), but it missing, why? I had used `z-index:-1;` to their parent and `z-index: 1` to their child so that become the child can raise above, but it doesn't work. I had used `background: transparent` to their parent, but doesn't worked either. It confusing my head. I was stuck at here for almost 3 hours, please help me.

this is my jsfiddle: [click this](http://jsfiddle.net/junaserbaserbi/t6x8w6av/7/)

This is my CSS:

```
#boxpost{
    height: auto;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #FEBA0E; /*orange*/
}
#commentleftside{
    margin-left:10px;
}
#bigbox{
    width: auto;
    display: table;
}
.colkiri{
    display: table-cell;
    border-left: 1px dotted #FEBA0E; /*orange*/
    z-index: 1;
}
.colkirichild{
    width: 20px;
}
.colkanan{
    display: table-cell;
    z-index: 1;
}
.colkanankedip{
    display: table-cell;
    background-color: yellow;
}
.colkananchild{
    border-left: 1px dotted #FEBA0E; /*orange*/
    float: left;
}
#username{
    white-space:nowrap;
    padding-top: 5px;
}
#username:before{
    content:"\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a";
    text-decoration:line-through;
    color: #FEBA0E;
}
.usernamechild{
    color: #369; /*biru gelap*/
    font-size: 70%;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: verdana; /*nempel tulisannya*/
}
.usernamechild a {
    color: #369; /*biru gelap*/
    text-decoration: none;
}
.usernamechild a:hover {
    color: #369; /*biru gelap*/
    text-decoration: underline;
    mouse: pointer;
}
#comment{
    font-family: normal x-small verdana,arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
    font-weight: 400;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    background: transparent;
    z-index: -1;
}
#comment:before{
    text-decoration: none;
    float:left;
}
.commentchild{
    display: table;
    padding-left: 38px;
    background: transparent;
}
.countdown{
    color: #888;
    font-size: x-small;
    font: normal x-small verdana,arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
}
#reportthis {
    color: #7d7d7c; /*abu-abu gelap*/
    font-size: 70%;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: sans-serif; /*nempel tulisannya*/
    word-spacing: 1px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding-left: 38px;
    background: transparent;
    z-index: -1;
}
#reportthis a {
    color: #7d7d7c;/*abu-abu gelap*/
    text-decoration: none;
}
#reportthis a:hover {
    color: #7d7d7c;/*abu-abu gelap*/
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

This is my PHP:

```
        while($f=mysql_fetch_object($q)){
            include("cdglobal.php");
            echo "
                <div id='bigbox'>
            ";
            for($a=1;$a<=$f->hor;$a++){
                echo "
                    <div class='colkiri'>
                        <div class='colkirichild'></div>
                    </div>
                ";
            }
            echo "".($f->ver==$ver?"<div class='colkanankedip'>":"<div class='colkanan'>")."
                        <div class='colkananchild'>
                            <div id='username'>
                                <span class='usernamechild'><a href='/indexprofile.php?hal=1&un=$f->username'><img src='".($f->foto=="none"?"/img/nophoto.jpg":"$f->foto")."' width='15' height='15' class='bayangan'></img> $f->username</a></span> <span class='countdown'>$countdown</span>
                            </div>
                            <div id='comment'>
                                <div class='commentchild'>$f->comment</div> 
                                <div id='reportthis'>
                                    <span id='idreply$f->ver$f->username' onclick='clickreply(this)'>reply</span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            ";
        }
```

Comment: You can't give a child a higher z-index than it's parent. And for it to work at all, the element would need any position other than static to start out with.

Comment: **You can't give a child a higher z-index than it's parent**, I just knew it right now, thank you Shikkediel for your information.

Comment: No problem, didn't state that very clear but I guess it came across. Don't forget the second point though, I don't see a position specified on the element so it will default to static and z-index will have no effect.

Comment: you are right @Shikkediel, **z-index will have no effect.**,  **it came across**, ok i recored it.

Comment: thank you @afelixj for editing.

Comment: @Shikkediel, so **<div id='comment'>** must be removed from there, to become not their child anymore?

Comment: Did you set position? Z-index without `position` property defined, doesn't work.

Comment: not yet @slick, if it required? ok I'm trying.

Comment: @slick, where should i put that position? Actually I don't really understand CSS much, the logic is to high for me.

Comment: Put `position: relative` or `position: absolute` (depending on what you want to achieve) next to every `z-index`. Well it doesn't have to be everywhere but when I see at this messy code, it's really hard to guess. Generally rule is simple - if you want to use `z-index`, `position` has to be set. Create fiddle. It will be easier for us to help. If you don't understand CSS etc. then maybe you should try to look for someone who will do the job for you.

Comment: **messy code** hahaha, okay2, you are right @slick. Ok I'm trying make a jsfiddle.

Comment: @slick, does JSFiddle want accept php? my php doesn't works there.

Comment: You do not post PHP. jsfiddle is for client side code. It's not a PHP parser.

Comment: ok, I'm trying to use javascript then

Comment: If you have the page live somewhere, you could right click on it and choose "view source", then copy and paste whatever HTML is rendered there to an online editor.

Comment: you are right @Shikkediel, I'm new in Javascript so it's so hard for me to convert it into Javascript, but I'm still trying.

Comment: I have made it in Fiddle guys, please look at [this](http://jsfiddle.net/junaserbaserbi/t6x8w6av/7/), where is the mistake of this css? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
  var c=2;
  var z;
  function mj1(){
   mj2();
  }
  function mj2(){
   username='michel jackson';
   for(a=1;a<=c;a++){
    z=z+"<div id='bigbox'>";
    for(b=1;b<=a;b++){
     z=z+"<div class='colkiri'>"+
       "<div class='colkirichild'></div>"+
      "</div>";
    }
     z=z+"<div class='colkanan'>"+
       "<div class='colkananchild'>"+
        "<div id='username'>"+
         "<span class='usernamechild'><img src='http://images2.fanpop.com/images/photos/7600000/Bad-michael-jackson-7647469-1787-2560.jpg' width='15' height='15' class='bayangan'></img> username</span> <span class='countdown'>5 minutes ago</span>"+
        "</div>"+
        "<div id='comment'>"+
         "<div class='commentchild'>Michael Joseph Jackson was born on August 29, 1958. He was the eighth of ten children in an African-American working-class family who lived in a two-bedroom house on Jackson Street in Gary, Indiana, an industrial city and a part of the Chicago metropolitan area.[12][13] His mother, Katherine Esther Scruse, was a devout Jehovah's Witness."+
         "<div id='reportthis'>"+
          "<span id='idreply' onclick='clickreply(this)'>reply</span>"+
         "</div></div>"+
        "</div>"+
       "</div>"+
      "</div>"+
     "</div>";
   }
   document.getElementById("showup").innerHTML="<p> "+z+" </p>";
  }
```

```css
 #boxpost{
  height: auto;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #FEBA0E; /*orange*/
 }
 #commentleftside{
  margin-left:10px;
 }
 #bigbox{
  width: auto;
  display: table;
 }
 .colkiri{
  display: table-cell;
  border-left: 1px dotted #FEBA0E; /*orange*/
  z-index: 1;
 }
 .colkirichild{
  width: 20px;
 }
 .colkanan{
  display: table-cell;
  z-index: 1;
 }
 .colkanankedip{
  display: table-cell;
  background-color: yellow;
 }
 .colkananchild{
  border-left: 1px dotted #FEBA0E; /*orange*/
  float: left;
 }
 #username{
  white-space:nowrap;
  padding-top: 5px;
 }
 #username:before{
  content:"\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a0\00a";
  text-decoration:line-through;
  color: #FEBA0E;
 }
 .usernamechild{
  color: #369; /*biru gelap*/
  font-size: 70%;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: verdana; /*nempel tulisannya*/
 }
 .usernamechild a {
  color: #369; /*biru gelap*/
  text-decoration: none;
 }
 .usernamechild a:hover{
  color: #369; /*biru gelap*/
  text-decoration: underline;
  mouse: pointer;
 }
 #comment{
  font-family: normal x-small verdana,arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  background: transparent;
  z-index: -1;
 }
 #comment:before{
  text-decoration: none;
  float:left;
 }
 .commentchild{
        display: table;
        margin-left: 20px;
        background: transparent;
        border-left: 1px dotted #FEBA0E;
        padding-left: 10px;
 }
 .countdown{
  color: #888;
  font-size: x-small;
  font: normal x-small verdana,arial,helvetica,sans-serif;
 }
 #reportthis {
  color: #7d7d7c; /*abu-abu gelap*/
  font-size: 70%;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: sans-serif; /*nempel tulisannya*/
  word-spacing: 1px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: transparent;
  z-index: -1;
 }
 #reportthis a {
  color: #7d7d7c;/*abu-abu gelap*/
  text-decoration: none;
 }
 #reportthis a:hover {
  color: #7d7d7c;/*abu-abu gelap*/
  text-decoration: underline;
 }
```

```html
 <div id='showup'></div>
 <input type='button' value='show' onclick='mj1()'></input>
```

Comment: Wow, amazing, I was making a little modification then seems more perfect, [look at this](http://jsfiddle.net/junaserbaserbi/t6x8w6av/9/). That's because of you @Paulo, It's cool, i like it. your secret key is line number 68,71,72. I never thought before, thank you Paulo, I'm learn from you Paulo, +1 for you Paulo. Thank you very much.